# PTIJ: Anthropomorphic sentient dishware using the Mikveh on Shabbos

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There is a Gemara in [Beitza 18a](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.18a.14?lang=bi) which says that vessels may not be immersed into a Mikveh on Shabbos (such as to Tovel a dish, which "fixes" it), but people may immerse (since anyone immersing looks like they're doing so to cool off, than for a Halachic purpose).

May Mrs. Potts and Chip (chinaware from [Beauty and the Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast_(1991_film))) or the dish that ran away with the spoon ([Hey Diddle Diddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hey_Diddle_Diddle)) immerse themselves into a Mikveh on Shabbos, under the guise of "cooling" themselves off, or do we not extend this idea to anthropomorphic sentient dishware?

[image: Dish running away with the spoon]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Mrs. Potts, Chip, and the dish are klei cheres, so they can't become tahor regardless.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If the ASD (anthropomorphic sentient dishware) *wants* to immerse itself, then we say that this is a *halacha* of *zeh neheneh ve'zeh lo chaser* - "this one benefits and this one does not miss out". I.e. since the ASD cools itself off (= benefit) and the *mikva* does not lose out, since we would not expect ASD to pay for using the *mikva* anyway (= does not miss out), therefore it is *mutar*.

However if the ASD is being forced to *tovel* itself, then since the ASD does not know that it is a *mitzva* to *tovel* itself (since it thinks it is being *tovel* itself as a sentient being and not as dishware), then it is not *shayach* to say that *mitzvos einan tzerichos kavanah* (*mitzvos* do not require explicit intention), and the *mikva* should then expect to be paid, since there is no *mitzva* being performed, so the *mikva* is *chaser* (looses out), and it is *assur*.